# How can I use the IEquatable Interface

Tags: c#, interface

I am studying about the types of Interfaces, but I don't understand how can I use the *IEquatable Interface*.

I think that it offers a better performance than using directly **a.Equals(b)**, because we avoid boxing...  I've done this:

```
public interface IEquatable<T> { bool Equals(T other); }
class Test<T> where T:IEquatable<T>
{
    public static bool IsEqual(T a, T b) { return a.Equals(b); }

}
```

But when I am going to call I get a error in the compilation, I am not very sure if I am calling correctly the method:

```
int x = 2;
int y = 2;
Console.WriteLine(Test.IsEqual(x, y));
```

The error is:

> Error CS0305 Using the generic type 'Test' requires 1 type arguments

**EDIT**: I am not very sure about this code, but it works:

```
class Test<T> where T:IEquatable<T>
    {
        public static bool Equals(T a, T b)
        {
            return a.Equals(b);

        }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x = 2;
            int y = 2;

            bool check = Test<int>.Equals(x, y);
            Console.WriteLine(check);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

When Do I have to use this code?, I read this in the book *C#6 Nutshell O'reilly*

Comment: For the way you've written your `Test` class you need to specify the type in order to call a static method. `Test<int>.IsEqual(x, y)`  Also `Test` isn't implementing `IEquatable` since it doesn't have a `Equals` method.  And finally that interface is for comparing the implementing class to something else, not for creating a static method to compare two other things.

Comment: @juharr I am getting this mistake 'CS0315  C# The type 'int' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method. There is no boxing conversion from 'int' to'

Comment: @JoseAviles Yes, and that's because of the constraint `T : IEquatable<T>`.  It's really not clear what you were trying to achieve here because like I said the point would be to compare `Test` objects or maybe compare `Test` to some other type.

Comment: Simply using the normal form, `x == y`, is much, *much* faster.  It takes a single machine code instruction (CMP) that executes in 0.25 cycles.  Interfaces are not a panacea, for one their methods cannot be inlined.  I guestimate it at least x10 slower.  IEquatable's primary use is to serve as the comparison vehicle for generic collections.

Comment: @juharr Can I use this example to compare the object x = 2 and object y = 2; ??

Comment: @JoseAviles In that case `x` and `y` are two different objects that box the same `int` value.  You'd have to unbox them to do a value comparison, which you can achieve by just doing `x.Equals(y)` since `int` overrides `Equals`, but honestly it's better to not box them in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `int` does not implement your `IEquatable<T>` interface.

Here I am posting you how your implementation should look like, but please consider what @MarcGravell is explaining in his answer:

```
public interface IEquatable<T>
{
    bool Equals(T other);
}

public class MyInt : IEquatable<MyInt> //you need an actual implementor of IEquatable<T>
{
    public int Value { get; set; }


    public bool Equals(MyInt other)
    {
        return Value.Equals(other);
    }
}

class Test
{
    public static bool IsEqual<T>(T a, T b) where T : IEquatable<T>
    {
        // Ensure your Equals implementation is used
        return a.Equals(b);
    }
}

var x = new MyInt { Value = 2 };
var y = new MyInt { Value = 3 };
Test.IsEqual(x, y);
```

Comment: (edit: no longer applies - you edited) actually, there's a problem here; by forcing `((IEquatable<T>)a)`, you've introduces boxing (if `T` is `struct`). It would have worked perfectly *without* that, but it would have been a non-boxing "constrained" call.

Comment: @MarcGravell I realized of that and removed the unnecessary boxing :)

Comment: Really I dont need this  no?  <pre>public interface IEquatable<T>
{
    bool Equals(T other);
}<code>

Comment: @JoseAviles no, look at Marc Gravell's answer. .NET already provides an IEquatable interface. My answer is merely to show you how you **could** do it, not how you **should** do it

Answer (score 3):

`Test` *isn't a thing* - only `Test<T>`. The first thing you could do would be to make the *type* non-generic, and the *method* generic:

```
class Test 
{
    public static bool IsEqual<T>(T a, T b)
        where T : IEquatable<T>
    { return a.Equals(b); }
}
```

Note this still isn't good - it won't work correctly for `a` as `null`, but... that doesn't matter because it *still won't help you*, because `int` doesn't actually implement *your* `IEquatable<T>`. It isn't enough to look the right shape - it must formally implement the interface. Fortunately, `int` *does* implement the *inbuilt* `System.IEquatable<T>` for `T==int`, so just remove your interface definition completely.

However, everything you are doing here is done better by `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`. I would suggest:

```
class Test 
{
    public static bool IsEqual<T>(T a, T b)
       => EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(a,b);
}
```

(note you don't need the generic constraint - it will still work correctly, using `IEquatable<T>` *when available*, and using `object.Equals` otherwise - also accounting for `null`, `Nullable<T>`, etc).

---

Note: if you *really are* just using `int` here, you should just use `==`:

```
Console.WriteLine(x == y);
```

The generic approach to equality should be used when you only know about `T`, where the *caller* provides the `T`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class which inherits **IEquatable**. Just like this:

*Note that ANY_TYPE has to be defined by you. It can be a string, int or DateTime for example.*

```
public class Foo : IEquatable<ANY_TYPE>
{
...
}
```

Now because you are inheriting an interface, which provides a method, you have to implement it. *Just put this Function into the class:*

```
public bool Equals(ANY_TYPE other)
{
    if(other == null)return false; // Dont run into null reference trouble!
    bool isSame = this == other; // or what ever you want to compare
    return isSame;
}
```

You can use a generic Type also. Create your class like this:

*T is the generic type you are handling (see [msdn generic types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters) for more information)*

```
public class Foo<T> : IEquatable<T>
{
...
}
```

Keep in mind, that you have to change **ANY_TYPE** of your Equals Method to T also!

I hope it helps you.